# Mysql 8 picking wrong index for group by date function

Tags: mysql, index, mysql-8.0

I have a table as below.

```
CREATE TABLE `alarm` (
  `alarmTypeID` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `vehicleID` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  `alarmDateTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `insertDateTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `alarmLatitude` float(10,8) NOT NULL,
  `alarmLongitude` float(11,8) NOT NULL,
  `fenceID` mediumint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `alarmValue` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and below is the indexes for the table.

```
ALTER TABLE `alarm`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`vehicleID`,`alarmDateTime`,`alarmTypeID`) USING BTREE,
  ADD KEY `fenceID` (`fenceID`);
```

I ran this query now.

```
select date(alarm.alarmDateTime)
FROM alarm 
Where alarm.alarmDateTime>'2019-08-01' group by date(alarm.alarmDateTime)
```

Below is the explain output but it shows the key as fenceID and possible key also as fenceID but in the query above I never used the fenceID field at all?

```
id
select_type
table
partitions
type
possible_keys
key
key_len
ref
rows
filtered
Extra

1
SIMPLE
alarm
NULL
index
PRIMARY,fenceID
fenceID
4
NULL
10197
33.33
Using where; Using index; Using temporary
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date(alarm.alarmDateTime)`

MySQL cannot use indexes for any column 'hidden inside a function call'.

<strike>Anyway, in</strike>

```
Where alarm.gDateTime>'2019-08-01'
group by ...
```

The most you can get is the use of `INDEX(gDateTime)` to help with the filtering.  Even so, if too large a percentage of the table is needed, that index will be ignored.

OTOH, a "covering index" would be best:

```
INDEX(gDateTime, alarmDateTime)  -- in this order
```

because it contains *all* the columns needed by the `SELECT`.

Grrr...  The query has changed.  Now it does not make sense.  Perhaps you want

```
SELECT  DATE(alarmDateTime),
        COUNT(*)                      -- adding this
    FROM alarm
    WHERE alarmDateTime >= '2019-08-01'  -- was just ">"
    GROUP BY 1                      -- shorthand for `DATE(...)`
```

*This* query would need an index *starting* with `alarmDateTime`, such as simply

```
INDEX(alarmDateTime)
```

`ALTER TABLE .. ADD INDEX ..;`

As for `DATETIME` vs `TIMESTAMP`, what does it represent?  Think of `DATETIME` as being a picture of a clock on *your* wall.  Think of `TIMESTAMP` as an instant in the galaxy.  The value of a `DATETIME` is frozen.  A `TIMESTAMP` is stored in UTC, converting from/to local time as you store/fetch.

`alarmLatitude float(10,8)` has issues

- `(m,n)` with `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE`
- `FLOAT` holds only about 7 significant digits, not 10
- 8 decimal places is overkill, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng#representation_choices

If you are tracking vehicles and need to keep huge amounts of data, see this for more tips on datatypes:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/schema_best_practices_mysql . (You have already followed most of the tips.)

Yes, another index will take space, but it may be worth it.

So, why did it use `INDEX(fenceID)`?  In InnoDB, each secondary key includes the columns of the PK.  So, it is effectively `(fenceID, vehicleID, alarmDateTime, alarmTypeID)`.  Since that was the smallest "covering" index for your query, the Optimizer picked it.  But then it used only one column (`alarmDateTime`), and not even the first column.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been **[moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97756/discussion-on-answer-by-rick-james-mysql-8-picking-wrong-index-for-group-by-date)**.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the index by an expression:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_name ON alarm (gDateTime, (DATE(alarmDateTime)))
```

If It will not help then add generated column and index which uses it:

```
ALTER TABLE alarm 
ADD COLUMN alarmDate DATE AS (DATE(alarmDateTime)) /* VIRTUAL */ ,
ADD INDEX idx_name ON (gDateTime, alarmDate)
```

Then use new column instead of expression in your query.